# How to change node.js app's ip and port?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to upload my node.js app to https://www.evennode.com/, but it's giving me an error saying

`Make sure your package.json defines the start script or the file app.js is your main script
Your app should listen on IP 0.0.0.0 and port defined in process.env.PORT`

My file's name is app.js so I don't think that's not the problem, so I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the second part of the error, so I was wondering how to make it do those things? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: post your package.json scripts and your server listen task?

Comment: @imjared is package.json the entire app? or what is it because I don't know if i have anything like that. my server listener that I was trying to use was 

`var server = connect().use(connect.static('public')).listen(3000, "0.0.0.0");

var port = process.env.port || 3000;

server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port' + port);
});` I don't know if that's the right way to do it, but it's just a combination of things I found on Google, still pretty new to node.js

Comment: not 100% if env are case-sensitive but you might try `PORT` instead of `port`

Answer (score 0):

What you need is adding the following syntax

```
process.env.PORT
```

Try doing

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```